# Swift: Encapsulated Layout Height always .333 larger than view

Tags: swift, xcode, uitableview, constraints

I am building a TableView filled with a variable number of cells. One type of those cells should have a fixed height of 69.0, but xcode keeps setting its encapsulated layout height .333 larger than what I set the height to, meaning it breaks the constraints because the encapsulated layout height is 69.333. If I change my Cell's size to 70 for example, the constraint is set to 70.333. I don't understand what causes this.

Here is the Cell:

```
class AnnotationCell: UITableViewCell {

//Set identifier to be able to call it later on
static let identifier = "AnnotationCell"

var annotation: Annotation!

//MARK: - Configure
public func configure(annotation: Annotation) {
    self.annotation = annotation
}
//MARK: - Cell Style
//Add all subviews in here
override init(style: UITableViewCell.CellStyle, reuseIdentifier: String?) {
    super.init(style: style, reuseIdentifier: reuseIdentifier)
    commonInit()
}

required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
    super.init(coder: coder)
    commonInit()
}

func commonInit() {
    //Customize Cell
    contentView.backgroundColor = colors.darkGray
    contentView.layer.borderWidth = 0
    
    //Favorite
    let favoriteView = UIView()
    favoriteView.backgroundColor = colors.gray
    favoriteView.addBorders(edges: [.top], color: colors.lightGray, width: 1)
    favoriteView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    
    let favIcon = UIImageView()
    let myEmoji = "".textToImage() //Test
    favIcon.image = myEmoji
    favIcon.contentMode = .scaleAspectFill
    favIcon.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    favoriteView.addSubview(favIcon)
    
    let stringStack = UIStackView()
    stringStack.axis = .vertical
    stringStack.spacing = 6
    stringStack.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    
    let titleString = UILabel()
    titleString.text = "Test"
    titleString.textColor = colors.justWhite
    titleString.font = UIFont(name: "montserrat", size: 17)
    titleString.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    stringStack.addArrangedSubview(titleString)
    
    let addressString = UILabel()
    addressString.text = "Test 2"
    addressString.textColor = colors.lightGray
    addressString.font = UIFont(name: "montserrat", size: 14)
    addressString.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    stringStack.addArrangedSubview(addressString)
    
    favoriteView.addSubview(stringStack)
    
    let editButton = UIButton()
    editButton.tintColor = colors.lightGray
    let mediumConfig = UIImage.SymbolConfiguration(pointSize: 20, weight: .semibold, scale: .medium)
    let mediumEditButton = UIImage(systemName: "chevron.right", withConfiguration: mediumConfig)
    editButton.setImage(mediumEditButton, for: .normal)
    editButton.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    favoriteView.addSubview(editButton)
    
    contentView.addSubview(favoriteView)
    
    //Define Constraints
    NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
        favoriteView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 69),
        favoriteView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.topAnchor),
        favoriteView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.bottomAnchor),
        favoriteView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.leadingAnchor),
        favoriteView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.trailingAnchor),
        
        
        favIcon.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: favoriteView.leadingAnchor, constant: 15),
        favIcon.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: favoriteView.centerYAnchor),
        favIcon.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 50),
        favIcon.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 50),
        
        stringStack.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: favIcon.trailingAnchor, constant: 20),
        stringStack.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: favoriteView.centerYAnchor),

        
        editButton.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: favoriteView.trailingAnchor, constant: -15),
        editButton.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: favoriteView.centerYAnchor),
        
    ])
    
}

override func setSelected(_ selected: Bool, animated: Bool) {
    super.setSelected(selected, animated: animated)
}
}
```

I am not setting the Cell's height in the TableView at all - I've tried that and that did not make things better. The Cell is getting displayed correctly, but console throws:

[LayoutConstraints] Unable to simultaneously satisfy constraints.
(
"<NSLayoutConstraint:0x281d21ae0 UIView:0x15cca3490.height == 69   (active)>",
"<NSLayoutConstraint:0x281d21bd0 V:|-(0)-[UIView:0x15cca3490]   (active, names: '|':UITableViewCellContentView:0x15cca42a0 )>",
"<NSLayoutConstraint:0x281d22120 UIView:0x15cca3490.bottom == UITableViewCellContentView:0x15cca42a0.bottom   (active)>",
"<NSLayoutConstraint:0x281d28820 'UIView-Encapsulated-Layout-Height' UITableViewCellContentView:0x15cca42a0.height == 69.3333   (active)>"
)

Will attempt to recover by breaking constraint
<NSLayoutConstraint:0x281d21ae0 UIView:0x15cca3490.height == 69   (active)>

I have tried giving every subview a fixed height (which does not make sense with a stackview in this layout) but that did not work either. I had the same layout in a view (not TableViewCell) without any issues, so I am guessing that it has to do something with the TableView.

Here are my constraints as seen from the view hierarchy, in case someone has an eye for it. I have opened up most constraints to make it as clear as possible. As can be seen next to the red arrow, the constraint of 69.0 seems to be there and I don't see anything different. The only thing I could see causing this issue would be the "UISysmenBackGroundView" which has a view inside it without any constraints.

[image: ViewHierarchy]

Comment: 1/3 pt sounds like a hairline thickness on a 3x device. Could it perhaps be the separator? If they’re enabled, does turning them off fix this issue?

Comment: @adeasismont damn, you're fast! I didn't know that was a thing, but indeed, setting tableview.separatorStyle to .none removed all of the issues. Thanks a lot! Feel free to post your answer and i'll checkmark it!

Comment: Thank you, and good luck with your project!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1/3 pt sounds like a hairline thickness on a 3x device. Could it perhaps be the separator? If they’re enabled, try turning them off to see if that fixes the issue.